# CSS Font styles not working

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add a css font style like the one on the landing page of http://www.lecrae.com. The text that says "LECRAE", I'm trying to use the same css style, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, only "W" in the word "Welcome" shows, and it doesn't look like the font too. Here's my code below:

CSS

```
.header { font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:14em;
    line-height:1em;
    color:#333;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:120px;
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="header">Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: Hey Josh, could you provide a working example (a Stack Snippet, including HTML - there is a button for it in the editor), so we can reproduce your issue? Also see this article: [mcve]

Comment: Seems to work fine on Firefox... Which browser do you use ?

Comment: @Lindow I'm using Chrome

Comment: Also note that the fonts you specified are not available in all OS, which means that a Linux user, for example, might actually fall back to `sans-serif`. You can use `@import` to provide the exact font you want to display; check out [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) for example.

Comment: Josh, how does your HTML look like? `<h1 class="header">Welcome</h1>`?

Comment: @domdom I have checked Google Fonts, but I have to buy that particular for $30 :(

Comment: @domdom yes, that's what my HTML class looks like

Comment: That's **very** wide character spacing. Most likely, the second and subsequent characters are extending off the right on some element and being hidden. Try playing with that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are three issues here:**

1. Only the first letter "W", of your heading "Welcome" is showing.
2. The font(s) you specified are not showing.
3. You want to use Futura, but it isn't available for free.

**The first issue** is solved easily. You are using a huge `letter-spacing` of `14em`, I assume you made a typo when copying the given source and it was supposed to be `.14em`. This explains why you can only see the first letter: all other letters are being pushed out of the screen.

**The second issue** is also solved easily. You are specifying fonts that might not be available on a users computer. For example, most Linux distributions do not ship with any of the fonts you specified and would hence fall back to `sans-serif`. If you really want to use a specific font, [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) that font from a source like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). This way, the font will be downloaded  by the user's browser.

**The third issue** is easy as well: you either pay for the font or you need to use a different, freely available font instead.

Putting that together:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700');
.header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .14em;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #333;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header">Welcome</h1>
```

Also note that you did not copy the `text-transform: uppercase` rule, which I added here.

Comment: Thank you mate for reaching out to me.